# Representative sample

Tags: sampling, representative

My question is about representative samples. My population is parents of children attending public autism-specific schools. I distributed paper-based questionnaires to all the parents in the public autism-specific schools in my country. The total population was 823 at the time of data collection. I used convenience sampling and received 234 (28.4%) completed questionnaires back from the parents. Is it possible to say that my sample is representative of parents of children in public schools in our country? Not sure if it is possible with convenience sampling or only in random sampling?

Comment: No, it is not representative since it does not include parents who do not answer questionnaires - but this is only my intuitive understanding.